# Can acpi-cpufreq drvier works for Intel Xeon processor?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, cpu

I want to use the `acpi-cpufreq` driver (instead of `intel_pstate`) to change my CPU frequency to do some researches, for the reason that I want to use the userspace governor. But here is the problem:

1. My machine is a server （Dell PowerEdge R730xd), with CPU:

   Architecture:          x86_64
   CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
   Byte Order:            Little Endian
   CPU(s):                40
   On-line CPU(s) list:   0-39
   Thread(s) per core:    2
   Core(s) per socket:    10
   Socket(s):             2
   NUMA node(s):          2
   Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
   CPU family:            6
   Model:                 79
   Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
   Stepping:              1
   CPU MHz:               1228.046
   CPU max MHz:           3100.0000
   CPU min MHz:           1200.0000
2. In Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, the kernel version is 4.4.153
3. I have disabled `intel_pstate` by editing `/etc/default/grub`

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quietsplash intel_pstate=disable"
   ```
4. After update-grub and reboot, use cpufreq-info will show:

   ```
   analyzing CPU 0:
     no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
   ```

5\ I have recompiled and reinstalled the kernel to ensure the ACPI Processor P-States driver is built-in.

So, how can I use the `acpi-cpufreq` drvier?
Many thanks!

Comment: Is the intel_pstate driver passive state available with that version of the kernel? The userspace governor would be available using passive mode, I just don't know if it has been backported. `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status` and `echo passive | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status`. To answer your actual question, yes the acpi-cpufreq driver should be available for that CPU.

Comment: Thanks! I have solved my problem. My early BIOS settings disallows the acpi-cpufreq driver to run. I have changed the BIOS settings to "OS control" and everything goes well!